# How can i create multiple components with pie charts?

Tags: chart.js, razor-components

I'm building a .NET Core web application.
My goal is to build a Razor Component containing a pie chart and then re-use that component in my project with different data inputs.
The problem is I cannot add a script inside the component which is required to configure each pie chart.

Here is what the component looks like:

```cs
@using PieChartProject.Models;

<div style="max-width:350px; max-height:195px;">
    <canvas id="myChart @Chart.Id"></canvas>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public PieChartViewModel Chart{ get; set; }

}
```

This is the code in my view invoking that component:

```cs
<div class="row">
   @foreach (var chart in Model.PieCharts)
   {
      <div class="col-md-6">
             @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<PieChartRazorComponent>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { Chart = chart}))
      </div>
   }
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

    <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); //this needs to be changed for every chart

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [25,75], //this needs to be changed for every chart
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.7)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.7)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(256, 256, 256, 1)',
                            'rgba(256, 256, 256, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        //label: ''
                    }],
                    labels: ['Yes', 'No'] //this needs to be changed for every chart
                },
                options: {
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: 'bottom',
                        labels: {
                            generateLabels: function (chart) {

                                var data = chart.data;
                                if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
                                    return data.labels.map(function (label, i) {
                                        var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
                                        var ds = data.datasets[0];
                                        var arc = meta.data[i];
                                        var custom = arc && arc.custom || {};
                                        var getValueAtIndexOrDefault = Chart.helpers.getValueAtIndexOrDefault;
                                        var arcOpts = chart.options.elements.arc;
                                        var fill = custom.backgroundColor ? custom.backgroundColor : getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.backgroundColor, i, arcOpts.backgroundColor);
                                        var stroke = custom.borderColor ? custom.borderColor : getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderColor, i, arcOpts.borderColor);
                                        var bw = custom.borderWidth ? custom.borderWidth : getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderWidth, i, arcOpts.borderWidth);

                                        var value = chart.config.data.datasets[arc._datasetIndex].data[arc._index];

                                        return {
                                            text: label + " : " + value,
                                            fillStyle: fill,
                                            strokeStyle: stroke,
                                            lineWidth: bw,
                                            hidden: isNaN(ds.data[i]) || meta.data[i].hidden,
                                            index: i
                                        };
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    return [];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    </script>
```

It all works fine if there is only one component, but I cannot seem to find a way to make it work with multiple components.

I added comments inside the script tag for the 3 attributes which need to be somehow changed for every pie chart.

I also found and tried the Chart.Js Blazor library by mariusmuntean and I couldn't get it to work. It didn't display any charts for me, I assume because it needs to be used inside a Blazor project and not in .NET Core MVC?

Any kind of solution for this problem is welcome, as long as I create the pie charts inside the Razor Component.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I was in the same boat as to how to create a pie chart in a Blazor Server App. I ended up creating a simple component to make an SVG pie chart and put it in it's own component. I have created a sample in GitHub that you use [SVG Pie Chart](https://github.com/MarianoJP/SVG-Pie-Chart). There is a small modification as well to make it into a Doughnut chart. All you have to make sure is that the data you pass to the component totals up to 100%. No point in plotting a pie chart that has a total greater than 100%.

The code is simple:

Data Model:

```
namespace SVG_Pie_Chart.Data
{
    public class PieDataModel
    {
        public double Percent { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Component:

```
@using SVG_Pie_Chart.Data
<svg style="display:block; margin:auto; vertical-align:central;" height="@height" width="@width" viewBox="0, 0, 2000, 2000">
    @foreach (var p in PieDataToPlot)
    {
        @(RotAngle = RotAngle + (((p.Percent / 100) * 360.0) - 90))
        <path d="@GenerateArc(1000, 1000, 800, p.Percent)" id="@RotAngle" fill="@p.Color" transform="rotate(@RotAngle,1000,1000)"></path>
        @(RotAngle += 90)
    }
</svg>
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public List<PieDataModel> PieData { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int height { get; set; } = 90;
    [Parameter]
    public int width { get; set; } = 200;
    private double RotAngle { get; set; } = 0;
    private List<PieDataModel> PieDataToPlot = new List<PieDataModel>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        if (PieData != null)
        {
            PieDataToPlot = PieData;
        }
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    #region Svg Pie
    private double DegToRad(double AngDeg)
    {
        return (AngDeg * Math.PI) / 180.0;
    }
    struct CartesianPosition
    {
        public double x;
        public double y;
    }
    private string GenerateArc(double cx, double cy, double r, double percent)
    {
        CartesianPosition Cartesian;

        double angledeg = (percent / 100) * 360.0;
        double anglerad = DegToRad(angledeg);
        Cartesian.x = cx + (r * Math.Cos(anglerad));
        Cartesian.y = cy - (r * Math.Sin(anglerad));
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Cartesian.y) == cy)
        {
            Cartesian.y += 1.0;
        }

        if (angledeg > 180)
        {
            return "M " + cx.ToString() + " " + cy.ToString() + " " + (cx + r).ToString() + "," + (cy).ToString() + " A" + r.ToString() + " " + r.ToString() + ", 0, 1, 0, " + Cartesian.x.ToString() + "," + Cartesian.y.ToString() + " ";
        }
        else
        {
            return "M " + cx.ToString() + " " + cy.ToString() + " " + (cx + r).ToString() + "," + (cy).ToString() + " A" + r.ToString() + " " + r.ToString() + ", 0, 0, 0, " + Cartesian.x.ToString() + "," + Cartesian.y.ToString() + " ";
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And how to use:

```
<SVGPie PieData="@PieData" height="200" width="300"></SVGPie>
<SVGDoughnut PieData="@PieData"></SVGDoughnut>
@code
{
    private List<PieDataModel> PieData = new List<PieDataModel>();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        GenerateSamplePieData();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
    private void GenerateSamplePieData()
    {
        PieDataModel PDM = new PieDataModel();
        PDM.Color = "#ff0000";
        PDM.Name = "Section 1";
        PDM.Percent = 30.0;
        PieData.Add(PDM);

        PDM = new PieDataModel();
        PDM.Color = "#ffff00";
        PDM.Name = "Section 2";
        PDM.Percent = 20.0;
        PieData.Add(PDM);

        PDM = new PieDataModel();
        PDM.Color = "#0000ff";
        PDM.Name = "Section 3";
        PDM.Percent = 20.0;
        PieData.Add(PDM);

        PDM = new PieDataModel();
        PDM.Color = "#00ff00";
        PDM.Name = "Section 4";
        PDM.Percent = 30.0;
        PieData.Add(PDM);

    }
}
```

As said, make sure your Percent do not add up to more than 100%.